# How to allocate char poiter to pointer char ** is it possible in C++ or do I need C for this

Tags: c++, pointers

Lets say I have `char pointer to pointer` now I want to allocate space for 3 pointers. I believe size of C++ char pointer is also 8 bytes. first pointer sized of 8 bytes will have strings that I will allocate later. I want to allocate memory for 3 pointers so I can access these pointers through `a[0][string_num] to a[2][string_num]` Then after all that I all allocate what a[0] pointer and a[1] pointer and a[2]   pointing what strings

```
char **a;
```

I tried something like this. This throws compiler error that

```
 a = new (char *)[3];
```

Error

```
 error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id
   11 |         a = new (char *)[3];
      |                         ^
```

In C this is possible. is it also possible in C++?

Comment: In C++ it's better to use `std::vector` and `std::string`. There's no need for "manual" pointers managements if you want to represent an array of strings.

Comment: What it looks like is you have looked at material for "C", or you have material explaining data structures using C++. In C++ the use of new and delete is not recommended (usually only used when writing libraries), and usually you can use classes from the standard library (like std::string,std::array,std::vector) to avoid new/delete. If you have to allocate memory yourself then have a look at std::make_unique (which will avoid a lot of memory leaks). And from my own experience I havent had to use double pointers since C++11 was introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put parentheses around the type.

```
a = new char *[3];
```

As an aside, if you are writing C++, use `std::string` for strings, and `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.